# I am getting error while I am using route guards in Angular, Error is showing like this, Cannot find name 'next'

Tags: angular

I am using Route guards in my angular project, and I am implementing route guards for Service component in my angular project. Now I am struck with one error and the error will be shown like this in the visual studio editor,  ->    Cannot find the name 'next'.
The error is showing when I am trying to use next keyword in auth.guard.ts  in angular project.

In auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  user = {
    role: 'ADMIN'
  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    if(user.data[0] == this.user.role)
    return true;
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

}
```

In app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutusComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'aboutus',
    component:AboutusComponent
  },
  {
    path:'services',
    component:ServicesComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: ['ADMIN']
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutusComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutusComponent,
    ServicesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have used the next keyword in auth. guard.ts  you can see this from the above code which is posted by me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace next by route as your data should be taken from the ActivatedRouteSnapshot (injected as route in your example).

Answer (score 0):

The next you're searching for it's declared as "**route**" in yout constructor. This will work for you:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  user = {
    role: 'ADMIN'
  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    if(route.data[0] == this.user.role){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nicola, I have done what you said from the above code. But the problem is import  { nextTick } from 'q' is not blinking and it is showing some error to resolve that error I have to import nextTick  so can you please tell me how to import nextTick.

Comment: remove it, it's an error. Sorry for that. I've updated the code.